# How do I copy a node tree in sling?

Tags: aem, sling

I searched a lot, but  I only found this:
[copy-a-resource](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/sling-api-crud-support.html#copy-a-resource)
Unfortunatelly this copies a single node only but not it's children (tree).

Answer (score 3):

The JCR [Workspace.copy](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Workspace.html#copy%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method does copy whole subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tree copy, but not ibn Sling but in com.day.cq.commons.jcr.JcrUtil (which is closed source)